# Dev c++ mingw no longer compiles

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, dev-c++, mingw32

I'm using Dev C++ 4.9.9.2 and my programs stopped compiling since yesterday.
My compiler error just looks like this:

```
 F:\Program\Makefile.win [Build Error]  [Program.exe] Error 1
```

With the compile log messages being:

```
Compiler: Default compiler
Building Makefile: "F:\Program\Makefile.win"
Executing  make...
make.exe -f "F:\Program\Makefile.win" all
gcc.exe Untitled1.o  -o "Program.exe" -L"F:/Dev-Cpp/lib"  

gcc.exe: Internal error: Aborted (program collect2)
Please submit a full bug report.
See <URL:http://www.mingw.org/bugs.shtml> for instructions.

make.exe: *** [Program.exe] Error 1

Execution terminated
```

And this is my makefile for a newly made project:

```
# Project: Program
# Makefile created by Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2

CPP  = g++.exe
CC   = gcc.exe
WINDRES = windres.exe
RES  = 
OBJ  = main.o $(RES)
LINKOBJ  = main.o $(RES)
LIBS =  -L"F:/Dev-Cpp/lib"  
INCS =  -I"F:/Dev-Cpp/include" 
CXXINCS =  -I"F:/Dev-Cpp/lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/include"  -I"F:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward"  -I"F:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/mingw32"  -I"F:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2"  -I"F:/Dev-Cpp/include" 
BIN  = Program.exe
CXXFLAGS = $(CXXINCS)  
CFLAGS = $(INCS)  
RM = rm -f

.PHONY: all all-before all-after clean clean-custom

all: all-before Program.exe all-after


clean: clean-custom
    ${RM} $(OBJ) $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJ)
    $(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o "Program.exe" $(LIBS)

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CPP) -c main.cpp -o main.o $(CXXFLAGS)
```

I've tried reinstalling mingw and linking a new compiler profile to it, and I've also tried reinstalling Dev C++ but this problem persists.

Both new projects and old projects that have previously compiled fine no longer compile...
Has anyone had any similar issues?

Comment: the url in the error takes you to very nice instructions on how to write a error report. Among other things it explains that a Minimal Self-Contained Test Case is needed. What is your code?

Comment: Any code. I've even tried doing a simple hello world and the results are the same.

Comment: are you compiling c++ or c code?

Comment: My example above was in C. Though this occurs on both C and C++ projects so far.

Comment: collect2 hints at a problem with linking.

Comment: Did you try to compile and link a simple program from the command line?

Comment: Gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something with the linker refused to work for me.
I installed mingw using TDM-GCC and made a new compiler profile for that, which ended up working.

I'm still at a loss for why the included mingw suddenly stopped working and didnt work properly even after reinstalling.